# Whisper based speech to subtitles python script - word timestamps issue

Tags: python, openai-whisper, whisper

Hello I'm writing a python script that takes a mp4 file in output and outputs a WEBVTT file of the transcription. I managed to make it work, but now I'm trying to reduce the size of each subtitle lines and get closer to word-level transcriptions in WEBVTT but I'm having trouble understanding how to set the word_timestamps parameter to True when implementing Whisper in a Python script.

I understand from this snippet of code (from https://github.com/ilanit1997/whisper/commit/819074f53caf056f814aa4ade50d85f56b4384d1 lines 440 to 443):

```
if not args["word_timestamps"]:
for option in word_options:
if args[option]:
parser.error(f"--{option} requires --word_timestamps True")
```

that you can set it using its command line argument, but I can't find out how to do it in my basic python script. (pasted it down below for reference).

```
import whisper
from whisper.utils import get_writer

model = whisper.load_model('base.en')

whisper.DecodingOptions(language='en', fp16='false')
audio = 'final_video.mp4'
result = model.transcribe(audio)
output_directory = "./"
word_options = {
"highlight_words": True,
"max_line_count": 50,
"max_line_width": 3
}

srt_writer = get_writer("srt", output_directory)
srt_writer(result, audio, word_options)
```

Sorry if it's not the place to ask or if it's something I should be able to figure out myself, but I'm kind of stuck.
Kindly,

Comment: I think it's better to use [whisperx](https://github.com/m-bain/whisperX) for this, it's faster, quite accurate and has already done most of the works.

Answer (score 0):

To use your word_option make sure you are using word_timestamps=True & task='transcribe' flags in DecodingOptions() or transcribe().

```
import whisper
from whisper.utils import get_writer

model = whisper.load_model('base.en')

whisper.DecodingOptions(language='en', fp16='false', word_timestamps=True, task='transcribe')
audio = 'final_video.mp4'
result = model.transcribe(audio)
output_directory = "./"
word_options = {
"highlight_words": True,
"max_line_count": 50,
"max_line_width": 3
}

srt_writer = get_writer("srt", output_directory)
srt_writer(result, audio, word_options)
```

Here's how you can do it in transcribe:

```
writer_options = {
        "max_line_count": 1,
        "max_words_per_line": 1
    }

    whisper_model = whisper.load_model("tiny.en", device="cpu")
    tts_combined_transcribed = whisper_model.transcribe(tts_combined, language="en", fp16=False, word_timestamps=True, task="transcribe")

    writer = get_writer("srt", tts_combined_dir)
    writer(tts_combined_transcribed, tts_combined, writer_options)
```